# Writing to a serial link continuously from a GUI program: need to use threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt4

I've written a GUI program with PyQt4 that has to send a message string over a serial data link.

I have implemented a GUI interface with two button widgets. I need to send the data over the serial link continuously, once per second when the first button is clicked, and then stop when the second button is clicked.

My current program is able to send data only at the instant a button is clicked. This is the method I wrote to handle the button click signal:

```
def sendMessage(self):
    while 1:
        print "Hello........"
        if checke == False:
            break
```

Do I need to use threads to solve this problem?

Comment: there are libraries (such as twisted) that can help with this kind of thing too

Comment: Hi, Twisted is a network programming, isn't?. Can I use it for non-socket programming? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The key to GUI programming is never do any long operation on the main thread, because it'll block the whole program until that operation is complete.

If you want to continuously send data over network, do it in a background thread.

Some example code for you.

```
class MessageWorker(QtCore.QThread):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ParserWorker, self).__init__()
        self.ok_to_send = False
        self.terminated = True

    def run(self):
        while not self.terminated:
            if self.ok_to_send:
                self.send_message()
            time.sleep(1)

     def start_send():
         self.ok_to_send = True

     def pause_send():
         self.ok_to_send = False

     def terminated():
         self.terminated = False
```

Then in the main program just call

```
worker = MessageWorker()
worker.start() # Start the background thread
worker.start_send() # Start sending message
worker.pause_send() # Pause sending message
worker.terminated() # Stop sending message permanently
```

Comment: Hi, I am new to thread programming, can you show me the way of easily understand(combining with PyQt-GUI programming). Thank a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It depends... if the send operation is fast, you can use the [QTimer](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtimer.html) class. It integrates with the Qt event loop so you don't have to worry about threading issues. Serial communications can be slow, depending on how much data you are sending, so I can't say for sure if this is the right solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use threads.  In any GUI-based program, any work that's going to take a non-trivial amount of time should always happen on a separate thread to avoid blocking the UI—whenever you see an "unresponsive" program, that's almost always due to the program failing to process window messages because its UI thread is blocked inside some long operation.

One easy way to startup a background thread is to use the [`threading` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html).  Here's how you might use it to write data to the serial port once per second:

```
class MyClass:
    # This method will run on a separate thread
    def _serial_port_worker(self):
        while self._run_worker:
            self.send_data_to_serial_port()
            time.sleep(1)

    # Call this to start the worker thread
    def start_worker_thread(self):
        self._run_worker = True
        worker_thread = threading.Thread(target=self._serial_port_worker,
                                         args=(self,))
        worker_thread.start()

    # Call this to tell the worker thread to stop
    def stop_worker_thread(self):
        self._run_worker = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have three options:

- Use a second thread to do the serial comms. GUI toolkits aren't always thread-safe, so you should only make calls to them from the main thread. Additionally, there is a limitation to threading in Python; only [one thread at a time](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) can be executing Python bytecode.
- Use the GUI toolkit's timeout function (might be called differently) to create an event every now and then. In the event handler do the serial comms. Make sure that you use non-blocking reads and writes (in [`pyserial`](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html), configure a timeout in the `Serial` object), otherwise your app might become unresponsive.
- Do the serial communications from the second program using the [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module. Even if the second process blocks, it won't affect the GUI. You can use [`multiprocessing.Queue`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) to communicate between the QUI and the other process.